# Installing python36 onto pfsense

Tags: python, freebsd, pfsense

I'm currently trying to install python36 onto the main pfsense system, this is so I can get netdata and a few other things installed.

However, I'm having problems with trying to find the command too download it. Just keeps telling me it can't find python, py36 or anything of the such, if you could please let me know the commands needed to download python 36 that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

pfSense is based on FreeBSD so you have to try

```
sudo portmaster lang/python3
```

(This will build from source, including its dependencies)

or

```
sudo pkg install python3
```

(To only fetch binary files)

To search about more python3 packages, then run following command in terminal:

```
psearch python3
```

Comment: Updating pfSense-core repository catalogue...
pfSense-core repository is up to date.
Updating pfSense repository catalogue...
pfSense repository is up to date.
All repositories are up to date.
pkg: No packages available to install matching 'python3' have been found in the repositories
Above is the error that it's giving me when I run pkg install python3, I've tried portmaster lang/python3 and it says it can't find portmaster, pkg install portmaster gives the same error as above, any ideas?

Comment: Can you run `psearch python3` and paste results here ? or `psearch python`